# Spring security авторизация через google и предоставление ролей

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth2

Настроил Oauth2 авторизацию через google, но не получается создать пользователя с ролью на основании приходящих данных.

Настройка google фильтра в SS

```
@Configuration
public class GoogleFilterConfig extends 
OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

@Autowired
private OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

public GoogleFilterConfig() {
    super("/login/google");

}

@PostConstruct
public void postConstructor() {
    setRestTemplate(googleRestTemplate());
    setTokenServices(googleInfoTokenServices());


}

@Bean
public UserInfoTokenServices googleInfoTokenServices() {

    UserInfoTokenServices userInfoTokenServices =
            new UserInfoTokenServices(googleResource().getUserInfoUri(), google().getClientId());
    userInfoTokenServices.setPrincipalExtractor(googlePrincipalExtractor());
    userInfoTokenServices.setRestTemplate(googleRestTemplate());
    return userInfoTokenServices;
}

@Bean
public OAuth2RestTemplate googleRestTemplate() {
    return new OAuth2RestTemplate(google(), oauth2ClientContext);
}

@Bean
public PrincipalExtractor googlePrincipalExtractor() {
    return new GooglePrincipalExtractor();
}

@Bean
public AuthoritiesExtractor googleAuthoritiesExtractor(){
    return new GoogleAuthorityExtractor();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("security.oauth2.google.client")
public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails google() {
    return new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("security.oauth2.google.resource")
public ResourceServerProperties googleResource() {
    return new ResourceServerProperties();
}


 }
```

Создание нового пользователя

```
@Override
public User extractPrincipal(Map<String, Object> map) {

    String id = map.get("sub").toString();
    User user = userDetailsRepository.findById(id).orElseGet(() -> {
        User newuser = new User();
        newuser.setRoles(Collections.singleton(Role.ADMIN));
        newuser.setId(id);
        newuser.setName(map.get("name").toString());
        newuser.setEmail(map.get("email").toString());
        newuser.setLocale(map.get("locale").toString());
        newuser.setUserpic(map.get("picture").toString());
        return newuser;
    });
    user.setLastVisit(LocalDateTime.now());
    return userDetailsRepository.save(user);
}
```

перечисление с правами доступа

```
public enum Role implements GrantedAuthority {
USER,ADMIN;

@Override
public String getAuthority() {
    return name();
}
}
```

отлаживаемый маршрут

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public String admin(HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request, 
@AuthenticationPrincipal User user, Model model){
    request.isUserInRole("ADMIN");
    return "admin";
}
```

request.isUserInRole("ADMIN") всегда возвращает false и поэтому аннотация возвращает 403. Как настроить роли, чтобы аннотации работали?